# Configure SSL Everywhere in URLs

Tags: laravel-5

How can I have Laravel return a secure at all times with the `url()` helper function?

I know that I can `url('foo', [], true)`, where the 3rd argument will set it to secure, but because I'm going to use SSL everywhere I don't want to have to specify it each time.

Furthermore, I don't have self-signed certificate locally.  I want `url()` to give an `http://` string locally, but `https://` on production.  Perhaps something I can configure in `.env`?

I've tried setting up [TrustedProxy](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy) but it didn't make a difference.  How can I go about this?

I'm *not* asking how to redirect `http` to `https`.  That adds an extra jump between clicking a link and loading a page.  I want `url()` to always give me `https` links when on production.

Comment: the ssl cert should be assigned to one domain name; let the framework use https:// to trigger it.

Comment: Even when viewing a page with `https://` the `href`s are still using `http://`